# Is it possible to refer to this form in template HTML in Angular 2?

Tags: angular, angular2-forms, angular-reactive-forms

I have a button as below.

```
<button type="button" class="button-next btn btn-primary" nextStep>Next
  <i class="icon-arrow-right14 position-right"></i>
</button>
```

It is under a nested Form Group with a `formGroupName="company"`. I want to disable the click event of the button if company is invalid. Also, I want to set dirty for all the fields in the `formGroupName="company"` so that validators will be triggered and error messages will be shown.

I can do this in `(click)` event of the button but I'm trying to find a best way to do this such as function taking `this` `formGroupName` as input and doing the operations instead of me explicitly passing the `formGroupName`. I have multiple formGroupName in the page.

I don't want to use `disabled` property of the button as I want to trigger validations on click of the button.

What is the best way to do as needed above ?

Answer (score 0):

In component set a flag of type boolean.

```
export class ComponentName{
    showHideFlag:boolean;
```

}

If company is invalid set flag to false else set it to true. In HTML of button use ngIf to show or hide this button as per requirement

```
 <button type="button" *ngIf="showHideFlag" class="button-next btn btn-primary" nextStep>Next
  <i class="icon-arrow-right14 position-right"></i>
 </button>
```

Comment: My question was how to pass `this` form. Not sure how I can use your answer. But thanks for taking time..